# On the completeness of solutions of a quantum particle on the surface of a sphere

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, spherical-harmonics

The Hamiltonian of a particle of mass $m$ on the surface of a sphere of radius $R$ is $$H=\frac{L^2}{2mR^2}$$ where $L$ is the angular momentum operator. I want to solve the TISE $\hat{H}\psi=E\psi$ and in order to do that I rewrite $L^2$ in Schroedinger's representation in spherical coordinates so $$\frac{1}{sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}(sin(\theta)\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial \theta})+\frac{1}{sin^2(\theta)}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial \phi^2}=-\frac{2mER^2}{\hbar^2}\psi=-k^2\psi$$ after some steps one can get $$\frac{sin(\theta)}{\Theta(\theta)}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}(sin(\theta)\frac{\partial \Theta(\theta)}{\partial \theta})+K^2sin^2(\theta)+\frac{1}{\Phi(\phi)}\frac{\partial^2 \Phi(\phi)}{\partial \phi^2}=0$$ having used $\psi=\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$. Now the two parts dipend on different variables so they must be equal to a constant, let's call this constant $m^2$ and I obtain two equations:

$\frac{sin(\theta)}{\Theta(\theta)}\frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}(sin(\theta)\frac{\partial \Theta(\theta)}{\partial \theta})+K^2sin^2(\theta)=m^2$  $(1)$

$\frac{1}{\Phi(\phi)}\frac{\partial^2 \Phi(\phi)}{\partial \phi^2}=-m^2$ $(2)$

The equation $(1)$ could be rearranged and written as:
$$\frac{\partial^2 \Theta(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{cos(\theta)}{sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial \Theta(\theta)}{\partial \theta}+[k^2-\frac{m^2}{sin^2(\theta)}]\Theta(\theta)=0$$
which is, by choosing $k^2=l(l+1)$ the legendre associated differential equation according to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLegendreDifferentialEquation.html equation $(9)$.

This leads to Energy eigenvalues $E=\frac{\hbar^2l(l+1)}{2mR^2}$.

**My questions:**

**1)**
How do we know that the   eigenvalues found are  *all* the eigenvalues for this problem? If $k^2$ had a different value, for example $k^2$=3, which is not a value obtainable with $k^2=l(l+1)$, how do we know that the differential equation would have no solutions?

$$\frac{\partial^2 \Theta(\theta)}{\partial \theta^2}+\frac{cos(\theta)}{sin(\theta)}\frac{\partial \Theta(\theta)}{\partial \theta}+[3-\frac{m^2}{sin^2(\theta)}]\Theta(\theta)=0$$ Does this TISE have solutions? How do we know that? Because if this TISE has solutions than I obtain the eigenvalue $E=\frac{3\hbar^2}{2mR^2}$ which is not in the list $E=\frac{\hbar^2l(l+1)}{2mR^2}$.

**2)**
Usually in quantum mechanics problems, we find the eigenvalues by imposing that our eigenfunction is $L^2$, in this case what we do is putting $k^2=l(l+1)$, does this represent the request that the eigenfunctions must be $L^2$?

Comment: That is, you are strictly asking about the spectrum of the operator $L^2$,  but setting it to a constant does not describe a free particle on the sphere. That is, you are looking for the spectrum of the [Casimir invariant of so(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_momentum_operator#Derivation_using_ladder_operators), for the unitary strongly continuous family of representations in a Hilbert space. These are unique. Essentially yes on 2.

Comment: cf. [here](https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/l/l039.htm).  You are using $L^2$ for both square integrable *and* the Casimir??

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sorry, by $L^2$ in the second question I mean "square-integrable funtions" and I don't understand your second answer, if $k^2$ is a constant, why can't we put it equal to $3$?

Comment: I am sorry, I was thinking about the radial equation of the hydrogen atom, not the  spectrum of ⋅ , which is not the Hamiltonian of a free particle on a sphere, of course, as you can appreciate in PW Higgs (1979), "Dynamical symmetries in a spherical geometry. I", Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and General 12 (3), p 309. But your question on the spectrum of this operator in QM is well-posed, without the "imagery" you started with.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sorry, isn't the Hamiltonian of a particle forced to move on the surface of a sphere of radius $R$ equal to $H=\frac{L^2}{2mR^2}$? I think I'm talking about something easier.

Comment: ***Of course not***! That was my original point. It's the kinetic term plus a radius constraint "potential". Higg's (and our) papers spell it out clearly and explicitly. You are *merely* investigating the properties of the Casimir operator for so(3) in Hilbert space, instead. As I suggested, PDEs amount to barking up the wrong tree, and matrix ladder methods, cf Dirac's book, is the way to go.

Comment: Hint: Do the classical case first.